# ¿Cómo contar la cantidad de ocurrencias de cada valor dentro de un vector?

Tags: r

Tengo una columna de datos donde `casa` es el nombre de la variable:

```
casa 
---------
azul
azul
amarillo
amarillo
amarillo
```

Me gustaría saber como puedo crear una columna en R que cuente las veces que aparece cada color consecutivamente empezando en 1. De forma que el resultado debería ser el siguiente:

variable nueva:

```
1
2
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma bastante sencilla es generando las secuencias por cada grupo, algo así:

```
casa <- c('azul', 'azul', 'amarillo', 'amarillo', 'amarillo')
sequence(rle(casa)$lengths)

[1] 1 2 1 2 3
```

En este caso usamos [`rle()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/rle.html) para obtener las cantidades de cada grupo consecutivo y [`sequence()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/sequence.html) para generar la secuencias de 1 a la longitud de cada grupo.

Comment: Gracias!!!!HA funcionado!!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías intentar algo como lo siguiente:

```
df<-data.frame(casa=c("azul","azul","amarillo","amarillo","amarillo"))
df
      casa
1     azul
2     azul
3 amarillo
4 amarillo
5 amarillo
cont$n<-1
n<-1
for(i in 2:nrow(df)){
+   if(df$casa[i]==df$casa[i-1]){
+     n<-n+1
+     cont$n[i]<-n
+   }else{
+     n<-1
+     cont$n[i]<-n
+   }
+ }

cbind(df,cont)
      casa n
1     azul 1
2     azul 2
3 amarillo 1
4 amarillo 2
5 amarillo 3
```