# contar datos repetidos de manera consecutiva

Tags: r

buenas tarde querida comunidad tengo el la siguiente tabla y requiero contar los datos repetidos pero que estos sean de manera consecutiva es decir:

```
SBAN    conteo

1313        1
1313        2
1513        1
1512        1
1512        2
1512        3
1512        4
1368        1
1368        2
1367        1
1397        1
1268        1
```

alguno podria darme una mano con una codigo? ya que uso table(base) pero me elimina los repetidos

Comment: Puedes agregar el código que has intentado? Si solo dices tengo este deber resuelvan no es bien recibido.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo contar la cantidad de ocurrencias de cada valor dentro de un vector?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/174388/c%c3%b3mo-contar-la-cantidad-de-ocurrencias-de-cada-valor-dentro-de-un-vector)

Comment: No señor, me aparece 1L cuando ejecuto la funciòn no se si es porque los valores se encuentra concatenados es decir 3052 AGROPECUARIA es uno de los valores

Answer (score 1):

lo logre resolver de la siguiente manera

```
df %>% 
   group_by (columna) %>% 
   mutate(counter=row_number())
```